# Convergence in distribution and ordered statistics

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d from some distribution $F$. Denote the ordered statistic of the previous as $X_{(1)}, X_{(2)},\ldots, X_{(n)}$. For $t \in \mathbb R$, define $Z_n = \frac{i}{n}$ if and only if $X_{(i)} \leq t < X_{(i+1)}$. What does $Z_n$ converge in distribution to as $n\to\infty$?

I'm thinking that $Z_n$ converges in distribution to $0$.  The pdf for $Z_n$ will get flatter and flatter as $n\to\infty$.  Am I right? If so is there a rigorous way to prove this?

Comment: The $X_{(i)}$ will distribute as $F$, and the $Z_n$ are steps like a  histogram between those, so I'd guess it goes to $F$.